# Live Smooth Streaming in IIS from webcam using FFMPEG

Tags: iis, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to do a live stream of video captured by my webcam and host it on IIS using Live Smooth Streaming. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. In the IIS manager's MIME Types add a new extension: `.isml` with type: `application/atom+xml`
2. In the IIS manager add a publishing point (filename: `myStream.isml`).
3. Start the publishing point.
4. Run the following command:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f dshow -rtbufsize 100000k -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -s 854x480 -f ismv http://localhost/myStream.isml/Stream(video)`

5. Play the stream from the location `http://localhost/myStream.isml/manifest` using VLC.

The problem is that the playback stops a few seconds before the moment in which I opened the stream with VLC. If I reopen the stream again, it will play from around the moment the first playback stopped to the moment the second playback started.

**What I'm trying to achieve is to make the clients see the video from the moment they open the stream to the moment they disconnect.** A delay up to a few seconds is acceptable. Obviously, the playback should not end regardless of the connection moment.

How can I do this? Should I change something in the FFMPEG's command or in the IIS?

Note: A solution using tools other than FFMPEG is acceptable, as long as they are free (as in beer).

**EDIT:** Changed the description of problematic playback.